# How to add configurable attributes to flat product table

Tags: database, magento, attributes, configurable

I was wondering how to add configurable attributes to the flat product table. I have attributes of size and color with "Use To Create Configurable Product" = Yes, and when I change "Used in Product Listing" to Yes and reindex, I get size, size_value and color, color_value fields added to my flat product table, but there is no data in it for any products, however my configurable products do have values for size and color.

Changing an attribute to "Used in Product Listing" = Yes works well for general attributes , but doesn't seem to work for configurable attributes.  Can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the Simple products are missing values for size and color? I would expect Simple types to have values but not Configurable types.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant for the simple products which are children of configurable products.  I'm not sure why, but on the Index Management page, I clicked on the link next to Product Flat Data  to "Reindex Data", it added my fields to the flat product table, but no data (all were null).  But when I actually clicked into Product Flat Data from Index Management, and clicked on the BUTTON for Reindex Data, then the data for my fields was included in my flat product table.  So this is no longer an issue.